# rails asset precompile is giving me a sass error

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

I am getting an error when trying to precompile my asses, specifically when it is parsing the sass files I get:

> Sass::SyntaxError: List index is 7 but list is only 6 items long for
>   `nth'

This is the command I am running:

```
$ rake assets:precompile
yarn install v1.10.1
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "@rails/webpacker > postcss-cssnext@3.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "caniuse-lite@^1.0.30000697".
warning " > webpack-dev-server@2.11.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0".
warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
✨  Done in 11.76s.
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: List index is 7 but list is only 6 items long for `nth'
/Users/blank/git/app123/web/node_modules/primer-support/lib/variables/layout.scss:31
```

In the same error it shows this:

> Caused by: ArgumentError: List index is 7 but list is only 6 items
>   long
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sass-3.5.7/lib/sass/script/value/list.rb:108:in
>   `assert_valid_index'
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sass-3.5.7/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:2024:in`
>   nth'
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sass-3.5.7/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:151:in
>   `block in _perform'
>   /Users/blank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sass-3.5.7/lib/sass/stack.rb:108:in`
>   block in with_function'

The line in question looks like:

```
// Aliases for easy use
$spacer-0: nth($spacers, 1) !default; // 0
$spacer-1: nth($spacers, 2) !default; // 4px
$spacer-2: nth($spacers, 3) !default; // 8px
$spacer-3: nth($spacers, 4) !default; // 16px
$spacer-4: nth($spacers, 5) !default; // 24px
$spacer-5: nth($spacers, 6) !default; // 32px
$spacer-6: nth($spacers, 7) !default; // 40px
```

https://github.com/primer/primer/blob/master/modules/primer-support/lib/variables/layout.scss#L31

What is wrong with that sass-wise?

Comment: Looks like your `$spacers` only have 7 elements (0..6) but you are trying to access element at position 7 which is out of range?

Comment: @HDox nth is 1 based http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#nth-instance_method so it is correct.